# Find the size of OLE/binary data in MSAccess DB

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to find a function in MSAccess that can be used to return the size of data (in bytes). e.g something like

```
SELECT x.id, sizeof(x.custom_data) AS size
```

Specifically for OLE data types but anything more general would be cool.

Comment: The ISO/ANSI SQL-92 Standard provides for DATALENGTH() function for this. Microsoft SQL Server supports it but the Access Database Engine does not :(

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are going to want to look at is the [ADO Stream object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258038).  This data type has a Size property.  Here is [another link](http://www.w3schools.com/ADO/ado_ref_stream.asp) that shows some more of the methods and properties of this data type.  Note that you will need to have  a reference set to the **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.5 Object Library** as specified on the Microsoft page.

Comment: I'm meaning to do this using SQL only... however it looks like Access doesn't provide such a mechanism.